# Typo3: Can't remove link from YAML-Header in

Tags: typo3

Like the title says I have a website made with Typo3. I have a link in the yaml-header an can't remove it, because I don't find where it is added.
I know that in Template View on the Root Page in the Constant Editor the sites displayed there can be edited:
[image: added Links]

And I also know that it's possible to add some links with Typo-Script, looks similar to that I think:

```
lib.header.20.30 = TEXT
lib.header.20.30.value = Link1 Name
lib.header.20.30.typolink.parameter = http://link1.ziel
```

The Problem is, that I don't find the link I want to remove not in the headernavigationincludelist neither in the Typo-Script.

Constants:

```
### Change message, if user did not fill out mandatory fields:
styles.content.mailform.badMess = Leere Pflichtfelder:
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
styles.content.mailform.badMess = You must fill in these fields:
[global]
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
styles.content.mailform.badMess = Change Me:
[global]
### Change settings of Dropdown Sitemap extension:
plugin {
  tx_dropdownsitemap_pi1 {
    picture {
      params = hspace="5" vspace="0" border="0"
    }
  }
}
### Begin of standard constants
### Only Yes/No options are listed here, for others see constant editor.
## searchbox
searchBoxOff = 0
## header
topNavOff = 0
firstHeaderImageOff = 0
secondHeaderImageOff = 0
linkFirstImageToggle = 1
noGifBuilderForFirstHeaderImage = 1
noGifBuilderForSecondHeaderImage = 1
## teaser
teaserOff = 1
rootlineOff = 0
languageMenuOff = 0
fontSizeSelectorOff = 0
dateAndTimeOff = 0
## basics
selectorBoxOff = 0
tabNavigationOff = 0
subMenuOff = 0
menuHeadlineOff = 1
subMenuExpandToggle = 0
footerOff = 0
## languages
languageLocaleStandardLang = german
languageLocaleFirstLang = english
languageLocaleSecondLang = french
languageIsoCodeStandardLang = de
languageIsoCodeFirstLang = en
languageIsoCodeSecondLang = fr
## headlines
replaceH1withImage = 0
replaceH2withImage = 0
replaceH3withImage = 0
replaceH4withImage = 0
replaceH5withImage = 0
## statistics
statisticsSetting = 0
statApacheSetting = 0
statMysqlSetting = 0
## expert settings
userAdmPanelOn = 1
userIndexingOn = 1
userIndexExternalsOn = 0
userDisablePrefComm = 0
yamlDebugOn = 0
yamlFillerLinkOn = 0
footerFirstLangHtmlCode = <div class="left">Born Informatik AG, Berner Technopark, Morgenstrasse 129, CH-3018 Bern</div><div class="right">Copyright &copy; 2008 Born Informatik AG</div>
footerStandardLangHtmlCode = <div class="left">Born Informatik AG, Berner Technopark, Morgenstrasse 129, CH-3018 Bern</div><div class="right">Copyright &copy; 2008 Born Informatik AG</div>
footerSecondLangHtmlCode = <div class="left">Born Informatik AG, Berner Technopark, Morgenstrasse 129, CH-3018 Bern</div><div class="right">Copyright &copy; 2008 Born Informatik AG</div>

searchPagePID = 32
plugin.tt_news.archiveTypoLink.parameter = 32
styles.content.imgtext.maxW = 410
plugin.wtsnowstorm.pid = 1,1
plugin.tx_srlanguagemenu_pi1.showCurrent = 0


plugin.meta = name=google-site-verification
headerNavigationIncludeList = 128, 31, 33, 34

TSConstantEditor.yaml-header.5 = topNavOff, headerNavigationIncludeList
```

Setup:

```
###############################
# Delete default styles of
# Plugin dropdown sitemap
###############################
plugin.tx_dropdownsitemap_pi1._CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE >
###############################
# Delete default styles of
# cssstyledcontent (Copied to content.css, in order to be able to modify them there.)
###############################
plugin.tx_cssstyledcontent._CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE >
###############################
# Configuration of Statistics
###############################
page.headerData.100 < plugin.tx_kestats_pi1
###############################
# metatags-config
# Insert your own data here.
###############################
plugin.meta {
  flags.useSecondaryDescKey = 0
  flags.alwaysGlobalDescription = 1
  flags.alwaysGlobalKeywords = 1
  global.author = Born Informatik AG
  global.email =
  global.copyright = Born Informatik AG
  global.keywords = Born Informatik AG
  global.description = Born Informatik AG
  global.revisit = 2 days
  global.robots = index,follow
  global.language = {$languageIsoCodeStandardLang}
}
#### Change language, keywords and description for first foreign language
[globalVar = GP:L = {$firstForeignLanguage}]
plugin.meta.global.language = {$languageIsoCodeFirstLang}
plugin.meta.global.keywords = my keywords for first foreign language
plugin.meta.global.description = my description for first foreign language
[global]
#### Change language, keywords and description for second foreign language
[globalVar = GP:L = {$secondForeignLanguage}]
plugin.meta.global.language = {$languageIsoCodeSecondLang}
plugin.meta.global.keywords = my keywords for second foreign language
plugin.meta.global.description = my description for second foreign language
[global]
page.headerData.999 < plugin.meta
###############################
# Configuration of newloginbox
###############################
plugin.tx_newloginbox_pi1._CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE >
plugin.tx_newloginbox_pi3._CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE >
###############################
# Configuration of tt_news
###############################
plugin.tt_news {
  _CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE >
  usePagesRelations = 1
  usePiBasePagebrowser = 1
  archiveTitleCObject {
    10.strftime = %B - %Y
  }
  getRelatedCObject {
    10.1.20.strftime = %d.%m.%y %H:%M
    10.2.20.strftime = %d.%m.%y %H:%M
    10.default.20.strftime = %d.%m.%y %H:%M
  }
  displaySingle {
    date_stdWrap.strftime= %d.%m.%Y
    time_stdWrap.strftime= %H:%M
    age_stdWrap.age = &nbsp;Minuten | Stunden | Tage | Jahre
  }
  displayLatest {
    date_stdWrap.strftime= %d.%m.%y
    time_stdWrap.strftime= %H:%M
  }
  displayList {
    date_stdWrap.strftime= %A %d. %B %Y
    time_stdWrap.strftime= %d.%m.%y %H:%M
  }
}
plugin.tt_news {
  catOrderBy = title
  displayCatMenu {
    catmenuRootIconFile = EXT:tt_news/res/tt_news_cat.gif
    catmenuNoRootIcon = 0
    catmenuIconMode = -1
  }
}
plugin.tt_news {
  pageBrowser {
    dontLinkActivePage = 1
    maxPages = 10
    showRange = 0
    showPBrowserText = 1
    showResultCount = 0
    showFirstLast = 0
  }
}
plugin.tt_news.displayLatest.subheader_stdWrap.crop = 100 | ... | 1
#### Change news-settings for first foreign language
[globalVar = GP:L = {$firstForeignLanguage}]
plugin.tt_news.getRelatedCObject.10.1.20.strftime = %d.%m.%y %H:%M
plugin.tt_news.getRelatedCObject.10.2.20.strftime = %d.%m.%y %H:%M
plugin.tt_news.getRelatedCObject.10.default.20.strftime = %d.%m.%y %H:%M
plugin.tt_news.displaySingle.date_stdWrap.strftime= %d.%m.%Y
plugin.tt_news.displaySingle.time_stdWrap.strftime= %H:%M
plugin.tt_news.displaySingle.age_stdWrap.age = &nbsp;Minutes | Hours | Days | Years
plugin.tt_news.displayLatest.date_stdWrap.strftime= %m/%d/%y
plugin.tt_news.displayLatest.time_stdWrap.strftime= %H:%M
plugin.tt_news.displayList.date_stdWrap.strftime= %A %d. %B %Y
plugin.tt_news.displayList.time_stdWrap.strftime= %d.%m.%y %H:%M
[global]
#### Change news-settings for second foreign language
[globalVar = GP:L = {$secondForeignLanguage}]
plugin.tt_news.displaySingle.age_stdWrap.age = &nbsp;Minutes | Heures | Jours | Ans
[global]
################################
# Configuration of indexedsearch
################################
plugin.tx_indexedsearch {
  _CSS_DEFAULT_STYLE >
  _DEFAULT_PI_VARS.results = 10
  forwardSearchWordsInResultLink = 1
  blind {
    type=-1
    defOp=0
    sections=0
    media=1
    order=-1
    group=-1
    extResume=-1
    lang=-1
    desc=-1
    results=0
  }
  show {
    rules=0
    parsetimes=1
    L2sections=1
    L1sections=1
    LxALLtypes=0
    clearSearchBox = 0
    clearSearchBox.enableSubSearchCheckBox=0
  }
  search {
    rootPidList =
  }
}
## CSS for rgtabs was moved and edited in content.css
plugin.tx_rgtabs_pi1.pathToCSS >

lib.nav.20.1.wrap = <ul><li class="home"><a href="index.php" title="Klicken Sie hier um zum Anfang zu gelangen"><span>Home</span></a></li>|</ul>
lib.nav.20.1.ACT.allWrap = <li class="active">|</li>
lib.nav.20.wrap = <div id="navmain">|</div>
lib.nav.20.excludeUidList = 2
lib.submenu.10.30.1.ACTIFSUB = 1
lib.submenu.10.30.1.ACTIFSUB.allWrap = <strong>|</strong><span class="hidden">.</span>
lib.submenu.10.30.1.ACTIFSUB >
lib.submenu.10.20.wrap = <li id="title">|</li><li id="separator">|</li>
plugin.tt_news.displayList.date_stdWrap.strftime = %d.%m.%Y

page.headerData.19 = TEXT
page.headerData.19.value = <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://born.ch/fileadmin/img/icons/favicon.ico">
page.headerData.19.value = <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="fileadmin/img/icons/favicon.ico">

#awstats congig
config.stat = 1
config.stat_apache = 1
config.stat_apache_logfile = intranet.log

# SNOWFLAKES!!

snowstorm = PAGE

snowstorm {
    typeNum = 3136
    10 < plugin.tx_wtsnowstorm
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        disablePrefixComment = 1
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0    
    }    
}

# Add javascript file to html header

page.headerData.3136 = TEXT
page.headerData.3136 {
    wrap = <script src="|" type="text/javascript"></script>
    typolink.parameter.data = page : uid
    typolink.additionalParams = &type=3136
    typolink.addQueryString = 1
    typolink.returnLast = url
}

page.10 >
page.headerData.28.value = <script type="text/javascript" src="fileadmin/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
lib.footer.100.value = <div class="left">Born Informatik AG, Berner Technopark, Morgenstrasse 129, CH-3018 Bern</div><div class="right">Copyright &copy; 2008-2011 Born Informatik AG</div>
config.sys_language_overlay = 1

lib.header.20.30 < lib.teaser.20.10
lib.header.20.30.languagesUidsList = 0,2

lib.header.20.30.defaultLayout = 2
lib.header.20.30.flag.CUR.doNotLinkIt = 1
lib.header.20.30.link.CUR.doNotLinkIt = 1
lib.header.20.30.links.CUR.doNotLinkIt = 1 

lib.header.20.30.link.NO.stdWrap.wrap = &#124; <div class="NO"> | </div>

page.headerData.2 = TEXT
page.headerData.2.insertData=1
page.headerData.2.case=lower
page.headerData.2.wrap = <meta name="google-site-verification" content="zc2lFQCXoXPUZrGCU-axHs4hoYSvruh2UsU9WgM_6VE">

page.headerData.3 = TEXT
page.headerData.3.insertData=1
page.headerData.3.case=lower
page.headerData.3.wrap = <meta name="google-site-verification" content="KCjWqRAjA0I77QRa9C909EPmEuX-UXb3vO213VBZeEg">
```

The link I want to remove ist the first one, the Intranet link:
[image: Links]

Thanks in advance, if you need more infos to Help me just say what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You surely have cleared the cache, I guess?
I'm wondering why in your listed TS constants there are five page-ids:

```
headerNavigationIncludeList = 30, 128, 31, 33, 34
```

The 30 is the ID of page "Intranet", I guess. It seems, your editing of the constants via the "Constant Editor" was not successful.

Comment: I don't know what page the id 30 has but also if I remove it, it doesn't change anything on the page.